# Assigning a Value From One channel:entries Call To Be Used In Another

Tags: variable, template-scripting

In my template I'd like to capture the entry_id of my main channel:entries loop, because I have subsequent loops where I may want to avoid that entry in one case, and invoke it again in another. So I'm looking for some way to create a variable that will allow me to do this. But the only user-defined variables I've found so far are the preload_replace ones, which happen before the channel:entries are run, so no good for my purposes.

Are there other user-defined variables I may have missed? How would you do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a job for [Stash](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stash). We may leave the template with two channel:entries tags after all, but only because we're running out of time. This will be a ToDo if we run into performance issues.

In fact, you should be able to store the entire record in Stash, and not need a second channel:entries at all.